# is it okay to develop ios App not using using latest Xcode version?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am in the middle development using Xcode 9.3, but the most recent Xcode version is Xcode 10, but most of libraries I use still not using swift 4.2 and I feel it still buggy. so is it okay to use Xcode 9.3 to develop the app and to deploy the app to the app store?

Comment: If you're using Swift 4, instead of 4.2, you can safely use Xcode 10 as well. You're good on Xcode 9.x anyway, though. (Although Xcode 10 has fixed A LOT of bugs from Xcode 9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For development, you can use any Xcode version you'd like.
For distribution, you can use the following versions:

[image: supported Xcode versions]

<sub>from [Apple's help page](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036)</sub>